# How to expose a url globally

Tags: linux

We have ruby application running in our server and we are able to access the application with in the same network through DNS and now my question is i want to acess the same url through internet/ globally. what are the steps i need to follow, Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Neelish

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming that you plan to host the site by yourself.

- Initially you have to purchase a static IP address.
- Purchase a domain name.
- Use the registrars DNS to map the domain to your static IP

Given that there are so many hosting providers and it's a specialized skill I would suggest that you host with one of well known hosting providers.